# Anacron daily job not being executed

Tags: anacron

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on a laptop with no other OS. I recently added the following line to the `/etc/anacrontab` file:

> 1 15  sync.daily  /home/steve/Scripts/syncStuff.sh

The script syncStuff.sh executes without problem and no output from the commandline.

I checked an hour after booting the laptop and the script had not been executed. I checked the logs and I found the following two entries for Anacron:

> (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d
>   /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start>/dev/null; fi)

And

> Started Trigger anacron every hour.

So it seems as though Anacron is running, but ignoring my entry. I thought my entry meant that Anacron should run my script once a day 15 minutes after the initial bootup. What am I missing here?

Comment: File names should not contain special characters like ".". Please, remove the ".sh" extension from the file name.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the file name from "syncStuff.sh" to just "syncStuff" and it runs ok from the commandline. I will now alter anacrontab and see if the script is executed tomorrow when I bootup. If everything works, and I'm sure it will, I'll report it back here tomorrow.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Your solution worked. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Anacron*'s configuration file [(man page)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man8/anacron.8.html) *`/etc/anacrontab`* normally contains lines like this:

```
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
```

The *run-parts* command which is responsible for running scripts in the specified directory *`/etc/cron.blabla`*, expects the file names to "*consist  entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens*" [(man page)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man8/run-parts.8.html) So, the script file names or link  file names you put under this directory should not contain special characters like "."

Your configuration is a bit different, because you have put the script name directly into your *`anacrontab`* file, but it is worth checking the file name and changing it to something *dot-free*.